# How do I make this sed replacement case insensitive

Tags: sed, case-insensitive

I need to modify a script, and I need to add a line before the first match of a "begin" statement with the string "some text" on its own line. The following command does the job, but I cannot figure out how to make it case insensitive:

```
sed -i '0,/begin/s//some text\nbegin/' filename
```

This fails:

```
sed -i '0,/begin/s//some text\nbegin/i' filename
```

...with the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 45: cannot specify modifiers on empty regexp`

How can I make this replacement case insensitive?

Comment: Which OS/distribution and sed version do you use?

Comment: @Cyrus Given that the 0 address works, I think GNU sed.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an address range including line 0, so I guess you're using GNU sed. In that case, there is an extension to the regex used in the address, namely an `I` modifier:

```
$ printf 'Text\nBegin\n' |sed '0,/begin/I s//some text\nbegin/'
Text
some text
begin
```

This matches case insensitively, but still always inserts a lowercase "begin". To avoid changing it, you can use

```
$ printf 'Text\nBegin\n' | sed '/begin/I i some text'
```

`/begin/I` matches case insensitively, `i` inserts the text following it on a separate line before the matching line.

To make sure this only modifies the first instance as in your example, you can combine it with an address range again:

```
printf 'Text\nBegin\n' | sed '0,/begin/I{/begin/I i some text
}'
```

Sed gets a little finicky with `i` and line breaks combined with braces, so inserting an actual linebreak seems to be required. The classical way is to have the argument to the `i` command on a completely separate line:

```
sed '0,/begin/I{
/begin/I i\
some text
}'
```

Or, briefer (hat tip to [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner)):

```
sed '0,/.*begin/I s//some text\n&/'
```

This captures everything on the line containing `begin` and inserts "some text" with a newline before the matched string, preserving whatever might be on that line already.

Comment: I'd assumed the point was to insert the correctly cased `begin` as was matched. Which means this would want to be `/\(begin\)/` and then `some text\n&`.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've added another solution that does that now.

Comment: I think just `sed '0,/\(begin\)/I s//some text\n&/'` does what you need here.

Comment: @EtanReisner That's more elegant. The only difference I can see is that the `i` version leaves the line containing `begin` untouched, and the substitution version at least swallows leading whitespace (or anything that comes before `begin` on the same line, actually) - which could be added to the match if needed. I'll add that.